# does elixir have its only function for send_interval?

Tags: elixir

In `Process` module, I haven't found function like erlang's function such as `timer:send_interval`. Does it exist or I have to call `:timer:send_interval`?

Comment: @David I doubt `Stream` module has anything to do with processes and timers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:timer.send_interval/2` is prone to the message box overloading if the handler takes more time to process than the interval. That’s why in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) we use the following approach with [`Process.send_after/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#send_after/4).

```elixir
defmodule MyMod do
  use GenServer

  @impl GenServer
  def init(state) do
    state =
      state
      |> Map.put_new(:interval, 5_000)
      |> Map.put_new(:schedule, nil)

    # optional; to be called if the first message
    #           from outside expects the periodic
    #           function to be called at least once
    # {:noreply, state} = handle_info(:work, state)
    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl GenServer
  def handle_info(:work, state) do
    # process periodic event

    # optional; to allow calling it from outside without
    #           setting many subsequent timers
    # if is_reference(state.schedule),
    #   do: Process.cancel_timer(state.schedule)

    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :schedule, schedule_work(state.interval))}
  end

  @spec schedule_work(interval :: non_neg_integer()) :: :error | reference()
  defp schedule_work(interval) when is_integer(interval) and interval > 0,
    do: Process.send_after(self(), :work, interval)
```

This approach guarantees that the interval would last between the time when the previous message has been handled and the new message.

*Sidenote:* to call [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) functions from [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), one uses the same *dot* notation as calling domestic functions (`module[dot]function`), e. g.: `:timer.send_interval` not `:timer:send_interval`.